# derive functions for generating projections for the interpenetration of two cylinders for making fittings

Tags: structural-engineering, design, chemical-engineering, machine-design, plumbing

​

I want to make custom fittings for constructing large molecular models using copper tubing.

I will need to cut a hole in one piece of tubing that will closely fit around another inserted piece. I thought about cutting a pattern on a flat piece of sheet metal. I would wrap this around the tubing where it would serve as a guide for a cutting tool.

I have [viewed this video](https://youtu.be/Wz7yGQUnIXE) that describes the interpenetration of two perpendicular cylinders. I am lost as to how to handle cylinders joined at an angle, let alone generate a projection that I can use for the pattern.

Can someone tell me how to begin deriving the functions to do this?

Comment: `can someone tell me ...?` is not an engineering question ... `how to derive ...?` is

Comment: Why dony you unwrap this in your CAD application?

Comment: Draw it - then take the view you need. A skill used by welders back in the day to work out the shortest weld distances as more weld costs more.

Comment: Just buy a tubing notcher.  All you need for drawings is the set-up parameters for the machine you buy. [Eastwood notcher](https://www.eastwood.com/eastwood-tubing-notcher-and-hole-saw-kit.html?gclid=Cj0KCQiAuP-OBhDqARIsAD4XHpf6UYVWfgHN0JbpRFJPKAp1kEEAYbxd0RfjhhKGzqBcAGwdL3TJS1MaAm57EALw_wcB&wickedid=559352078056&wickedsource=google&wv=3.1)

Answer (score 2):

[OnShape](https://onshape.com) is a useful free (if ou make your designs public) 3D CAD program. There's an introductory tutorial showing some of the techniques to create sheet metal cylinder on YouTube [TechProductDesign](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6Q4_c8_cu4&ab_channel=TEACHPRODUCTDESIGN) channel.

[image]

*Figure 1. The pipe with hole extruded from angled plane. Note the gap at the rear to allow the sheet metal flattening.*

[image]

*Figure 2. The flattened sheet metal pattern.*

[image]

*Figure 3. Intersecting pipe and cylinder. Note that Plane 1 is defined by the construction line at the bottom right and the point visible above the pipe intersection.*

Expect to put some effort into learning how to do this. It's not difficult but will take some time so do some simple exercises before you attempt your real project.